# Complete vs General Integral of first order PDE

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, differential-equations, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

The following is an excerpt from Landau's Course on Theoretical Physics Vol.1 Mechanics:

> ... we should recall the fact that every first-order partial differential equation has a solution depending on an arbitrary function; such a solution is called the general integral of the equation. In mechanical applications, the general integral of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation is less important than a complete integral, which contains as many independent arbitrary constants as there are independent variables.

Can someone clarify what's a complete integral and what's a general integral of a first order partial differential equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion "complete integral" here refers to solutions of specific (1st order) PDEs that depend on the maximal number of constants of motion. If you want a concrete example I can refer you to Equation (10) of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:0711.4115), or even better to Ref. [10] in that paper.

A "general solution", by contrast, need not depend explicitly on constants of motion, but usually contains some free (integration) function. As an example for a solution not depending explicitly on constants of motion see the "enveloping solution" in Eq. (11) of the paper above.

[I never encountered these notions anywhere, except when solving Hamilton-Jacobi equations - this seems to be also the context to which Landau refers.]

Comment: Landau does refer to Hamilton-Jacobi equations. Can you point me to some other references where the same notions are used relating to Hamilton-Jacobi equations (in classical mechanics)? Perhaps seeing them will clarify me.

Comment: I can refer you to the book mentioned in the paper I referred to in my reply. It is, however, in German: E. Kamke, Differentialgleichungen, Vol II. But I am sure there is some English book dealing with this. You might try e.g. A. D. Polyanin, V. F. Zaitsev, and A. Moussiaux,  Handbook of First Order Partial Differential Equations, Taylor & Francis, London, 2002. The notion of "complete integral" and "general solution" is also defined on this useful webpage: http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fpde/fpdetoc3.htm

Answer (score 7):

In the general theory of partial differential equations and specifically for *First-Order Partial Differential Equations* one defines the *general solution*(Landau's general integral) and the *complete integral* as follows:

> For a two-dimensional first order partial differential equation 
>   $$f(x,y,z,z_x,z_y)=0. \tag{1}$$
>   **Complete Integral**: A two parameter family of implicit solutions of the form (2) of (1) is called a complete integral of the partial differential equation.
>   $$\phi(x,y,z,a,b)=0. \tag{2}$$
>   **General solution:** A function of the form (3), where $u(x,y,z)$ and $v(x,y,z)$  are functions of $x,y,z$ and $\Phi$ is  an  arbitrary  smooth  function, $\Phi$ is  called  a  (implicit  or  explicit)  general solution of (1), if $z,z_x,z_y$ as determined by the relation (3) satisfy (1)
>   $$\Phi(u,v)=0\tag{3}.$$

*If we have a complete integral (2) of (1), we can derive a general solution (3), we would show this later in the post but first, let's see how to derive the PDE (1) from the complete integral (2).

If we have a complete integral (2), we can obtain $d\phi/dx$ and $d\phi/dy$ :
$$\phi_x+z_x\phi_z=0. \tag{4}$$
$$\phi_y+z_y\phi_z=0. \tag{5}$$

With (2),(4),(5) we can obtain an expression of the form (1) that is free from the parameters $a$ and $b$. If (1) is obtained exactly from (2),(4),(5) then $\phi$ is a solution of the PDE (1).

Now, to derive a general solution (3) from a complete integral (2), we can impose $b=W(a)$ in the complete solution (2), obtaining $\Phi(x,y,z,a,W(a))$, and impose the condition $d\Phi/da=0$,
$$\frac{d\Phi}{da}=\Phi_a(x,y,z,a,W(a))+W'(a)\Phi_W(x,y,z,a,W(a))=0. \tag{6}$$

With (6) we can write $a=A(x,y,z)$ as a function of $x,y,z$. So the general solution derived from (2) can be written as 
$$\Phi\Big(x,y,z,A(x,y,z),W(A(x,y,z))\Big) = 0. \tag{7}$$

We can see that (7) in fact matches our definition of general solution.Now we will prove that (7) is a solution of (1), again $d\Phi/dx$ and $d\Phi/dy$

$$\Phi_x+z_x\Phi_z+ \Phi_A A_x+\Phi_W W'(A) A_x =0. \tag{8}$$
$$\Phi_y+z_y\Phi_z+ \Phi_A A_y+\Phi_W W'(A) A_y =0. \tag{9}$$

Now applying the condition (6) Equations (8), and (9) yield:

$$\Phi_x+z_x\Phi_z =0. \tag{8}$$
$$\Phi_y+z_y\Phi_z =0. \tag{9}$$

Now the systems of equations (2),(4),(5) yield the same derived expression (1) as (7),(8),(9), now $\Phi\Big(x,y,z,A(x,y,z),W(A(x,y,z))\Big)$ is a general solution of (1) and we can see that we obtain a different solution for every function $W$.

We can see that this solution is free of the parameters $a$ and $b$, when we choose a particular function $W$ we obtain a *particular solution* for the PDE.

Landau's generalizes this result in his footnote, however he does it for an easier equation, not a general  First-order PDE (1). The steps he does are the same as we did for a general two dimensional First-order PDE.

Comment: What's the base to impose these conditions: $d\Phi/da=0$ and $b=W(a)$

Comment: This is related to the envelopes of a First-order PDE.

Comment: Hello, could you provide me with some source material for your post?

Comment: When I wrote this post, I used many sources. In particular, some of the derivation in the post is taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_partial_differential_equation . However I tried to make the article as self-contained as possible since most of the sources I found were either too advanced or had very extensive material but taking a lot of time to read. I believe if you propose some elementary examples (general solutions and complete integrals) for a particularly easy two-dimensional  first-order PDE, you would understand the material with only the information of this post.

Answer (score 5):

In Russian *"integral"* is a synonym of a solution of differential equation. *"general integral"* means general solution, *"complete"* probably means sum of particular solution and general solution  (called the complementary solution)

[iPDEs](http://www.ewp.rpi.edu/hartford/~ernesto/F2003/MES/Notes/Notes_pdf/s10.pdf)

Comment: This answer is very confusing. Particular solution usually means a solution to an *inhomogeneous* equation while what you and your reference mean is the same general solution, only with some boundary/initial conditions plugged-in.

Comment: thx, I corrected